# Do I need to run EF UI to include added non-clustered indexes?

Tags: entity-framework

I am using Entity framework version 5. In SQL Server database, I add a non-clustered index added for a column on a table. Do I need to run EF UI in Visual Studio to update the edmx file?  If so, where I need to do that with EF UI?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No, the nonclustered index is database-internal only - it doesn't have any impact on the entity data model (your `.edmx` file), so you don't need to update anything.

If SQL Server executes a query that will benefit from that new index, the query optimizer will use that index - and will return the data faster - but from the point of view of Entity Framework, nothing changes (no model properties need to be changed)